# How to create a function that will display number according to specific range. ex from 1-29 show 1, from 30-59 show 2, from 60-89 show 3 and so on

Tags: jquery

I need to create a function based on input value.
Example: if we enter number from 1-29 then show 1, from 30-59 show 2, from 60-89 show 3 and so on...

I'm new to this and can't figure out how to make that. Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this to make it more dynamic.

```
function getRange(num) {
    if (num <= 0) {
        return 'Invalid input';
    }
    let rangeSize = 30;
    let range = Math.floor(num/rangeSize)+1;
    return range;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function getRange(num) {
    if (num <= 0) {
        return 'Invalid input';
    }
    let rangeSize = 30;
    let range = Math.floor(num/rangeSize)+1;
    return range;
}

console.log(getRange(29))
console.log(getRange(30))
console.log(getRange(59))
console.log(getRange(62))
```

Comment: Checking for `num` after using it is odd.

Comment: `function getRange(num) { return num > 0 ? Math.floor(num/rangeSize)+1 : null }`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes I agree, I noticed it as soon as i posted the answer and was thinking "why did i do this". Thanks anyway, have changed it.